# Screenshot isn't taken - C# Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to implement a screenshot capture feature into my Selenium WebDriver tests like this:

```
[TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Failure))
            {
                Screenshot file = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();
                file.SaveAsFile(@"" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
                    + "/TestScreenshot" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
            }

            if (_driver != null) _driver.Close();
        }
```

If a test fails, a screenshot should be taken and saved to user's desktop. However, when the test fails there is no screenshot saved to desktop. The method does work because the last line (_driver.Close() ) is executed properly (it closes browser if test fails).

Is there an error in my syntax or something?

Comment: does your app has write privilege to that location? try your application as administrator.

Comment: What is the exact value of `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))`, according to the `Immediate Window`?

Answer (score 0):

Your application may not have the access to users desktop to write the file and Selenium Webdrive just catches and suppresses the error to avoid crashing the application.

Make sure (by giving privilege to you application) or saving in a location that does not need any privileges.